# Magento 2: a better workflow for .less / .css / .map generation with WeltPixel themes

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, magento2

Asked this in the internal WeltPixel forum, with no luck... so I try here:

---

Working on a large multisite with several websites, all based on child themes of [WeltPixel Pearl](https://www.weltpixel.com/)

I'm making changes in multiple less files. When I'm working locally I have grunt running to generate .less / .css and .map files so I can see in the browser which less files I have to edit.

This workflow is from **Magento docs**, using `grunt less` and `grunt watch` to automagically generate .css whenever I saved a .less file, and it worked perfect - I thought...

But now I discover that if I generate css with :

```
 bin/magento weltpixel:less:generate
```

and

```
bin/magento weltpixel:css:generate --store=STORECODE
```

AFTER i run grunt less, then I have other results, and the map files aren't generated. In the browser I only see **styles-m.css** and **styles-l.css**, so it's a mess ...

Whenever we publish for production, the last step is to run `weltpixel:css:generate` which is explaining why I had some incongruences between my local platform and production server.

So, I'm asking for : how do you build a development workflow that will let you modify some .less, generate .css and build corresponding .map files, so you can see in development tools in the browser which less files you should modify?

Any ideas?

/best regards

Comment: Apparently, Magento is using https://github.com/leafo/lessphp for compiling .less files. LessPHP doesn't allow source-maps yet, and the package seems old and discontinued.